# Effect Of Temperature Lag On Electricty Demand

Tags: lags

I am trying to analyze effect of temperature lag on power demand. I have half hourly power demand & half hourly average temperature data for past 4 years. Power demand does not rise immediately with temperature rise. It take some time lag to rise.  So I want to analyze effect of temperature lag on power demand.  (Means Impact of temperature at time (t-x) on power demand at time t where x is my lag).  I want to check which lag has highest correlation on my demand.

Comment: You could start with calculating a cross-correlation function,  and maybe show a plot of it in your post?  What about seasonality  (maybe lag structure differs between winter and summer?) ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, *analyze* vs. *analyse* is American vs. Brittish spelling, so no big need to correct, IMHO. But no harm there either.

Comment: @Richard Hardy:  OK, thanks, did'nt know. So now I know that my chromes spell checker is american ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yes my data is seasonal. Also for different time of day  my lag may be different. So how to proceed in such case.I have tried to first divide my data manually season wise.

Comment: Since you have so much data, I would start by modelling the data in chunks.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen:I have already classified data based on 3 season(Winter,Summer,Rainy).So i have three data sets to study.For each single day I have  48 values of demand and temperature data starting from 00 Hrs to 24:00 Hrs.(Half Hourly). So do I need to again create 48 sub data files representing every half hour and then analyse it every data file separately.

Comment: No creating separate data sets for each half hour would loose the tyime series aspect, which is essential here since you want to do predictions!  First you need to get an idea about cross correlation functions especially about how long is correlation time.  Then, when you split in blocks, at least keep time intervals of length of the correlation time together!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen:I tried to use cross correlation function.But it is giving highest value at 0 lag.Actually my data is not linearly related to temperature.For Example my demand at 12;00 noon will always be higher than electricity demand at 08;00 as at 12:00 noon all industrial supply are on.My electrity load curve has peaks at 12:00 Hrs and 19;00 Hrs. So which method should I adopt.Do I need to make series stationary.